# Read negative elevation data from NASA png tiles

Tags: c#, wms, elevation

I query [NASA JPL service](http://wms.jpl.nasa.gov/wms.cgi?request=GetCapabilities) using [query string](http://wms.jpl.nasa.gov/wms.cgi?Service=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&request=GetMap&layers=worldwind_dem&srs=EPSG:4326&width=300&height=300&format=image/png&styles=short_int&bbox=44,42,52,50). Response is a unsigned 16 bit per pixel png image and the values are elevation values in meters. Same is described in the capabilty xml of the layer as can be seen below:

```
<Layer queryable="0">
      <Name>worldwind_dem</Name>
      <Title>SRTM derived global elevation, 3 arc-second</Title>
      <Abstract>
    A global elevation model, prepared from the 3 arc-second SRTM dataset by filling some of the problem areas. Prepared by the NASA Learning Technologies.
    The default style is scaled to 8 bit, non-linear.
    It is possible to request the elevation data in meters by the short_int tyle and requesting PNG format. The resulting PNG file will be a unsigned 16 bit per pixel image. The values are then the elevation in meters.
    Values are signed 16 bit integers, but PNG will present them as unsigned, leading to a few areas with very large values (65000+)
    For elevation values in feet, request PNG format with the style feet_short_int.
      </Abstract>
```

When I read the elevation using following code

```
var pixel = bmp.GetPixel(rowIndex,
                         colIndex);
var value1 = BitConverter.ToInt16(new byte[] { 0, pixel.B },
                                  0);
```

I read the positive elevation value correctly but unable to read negative value. The query string tile mentioned above covers all the case, it has data for +ve, zero and -ve values.

Comment: Anything any suggestion or ticks?